# Lost root on Cyanogenmod 13 after Factory Reset

Tags: cyanogenmod

I am running Cyanogenmod on my Galaxy S2 for about a year.

A few months ago I bought a new phone and game my Galaxy S2 to my mom to use as a second phone. I did a Factory Reset before that. Everything was working fine, including root.

Recently I took the phone back and did a Factory Reset again, but now I lost root access. It is set to "Apps and ADB" in developer options btw.

I tried reinstalling Cyanogenmod, no luck.
Tried flashing recovery (I am using clockworkmod and it worked file all the time), no luck.

**EDIT**

[image: That's what happens when executing "su"]

Comment: What happens when you "su" in a terminal emulator?

Comment: @AndyYan, I've updated my question.

Comment: That looks as if you haven't enabled it (but you said you did). I'm at a loss.

Comment: @AndyYan, yes, me too. I tried flashing another ROM, based on Cyanogen. Same thing.

Comment: Why not flash just the SuperSU zip which will place all the files for su and the SuperSU app? and will re-enable root

Comment: Have you installed the [Superuser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu) app? Without su does not all you to become root.

Comment: @MikeN, it doesn't help.

Comment: @Robert, Cyanogenmod has it's own superuser stuff. You don't need Superuser app for that.

Comment: @geNia By "doesn't help", do you mean it doesn't boot or it boots but still no su? SuperSU is known to collaborate poorly with CM, but there are specific versions that do work.

Comment: @AndyYan, it boots but still no su. Was no su... I tried flashing it again and now the phone is rooted. But it is using SuperSu root instead on CM one. Anyway, it's strange.

Answer (score 0):

I tried flashing SuperSU .zip file and after a few attempts it worked. No idea what was the problem, but it is fixed now.